# Install and start a Windows Service via Code

Tags: windows-services

I want to install and start (2. Button Stop and Deinstall) a service from code in C#.Net Windows Forms.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ServiceController` class, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) to stop and start it.

To install, you can use `InstallUtil.exe`, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx).